# Using a different Superclass, instead of NSObject

Tags: objective-c, class, nsobject, superclass

This might be a straight forward answer, and I know that you don't *have* to set NSObject as the Superclass when creating a new class.

But say, for example, I wanted to create a class which held a set of custom CABasicAnimations. Although it may be perfectly ok for me to use CABasicAnimation as the superclass, is it recommended that I follow the unwritten rule and still use NSObject or would you, if you were writing such a class, use CABasicAnimation as the Superclass?

I would assume that it wouldn't matter as long as the Class only contained properties and methods relative to CABasicAnimation.

It would be interesting to here your thoughts!

Comment: `CABasicAnimation` inherits `NSObject` (indirectly) already, so if you inherit from `CABasicAnimation`, you're covered. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: My question is referring to other developers' preference rather than what works

Comment: I guess my point is that by inheriting from `CABasicAnimation`, you're _already matching_ other developers' preferences. When they say "you should always subclass `NSObject`", they're parenthetically including "(or something that subclasses `NSObject` for you)".

Comment: In fact, you don't have to set a superclass at all -- by not specifying a superclass you are creating a new root class. Probably not what you were looking for though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is to subclass whatever object you are trying to extend. NSObject is used for many subclasses because it is the root object, but if I was going to write a class that was very similar to NSTableView, then I would subclass NSTableView.

In your case, if you are writing a custom animation that you want to call, then you should consider subclassing from CABasicAnimation. On the other hand, if you animation is really just a collection of pre-exisiting CA animations, then NSObject would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

> a class which held a set of custom CABasicAnimations.

In this case, I'd like to use [**Category**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) instead of **Subclass**.